# Join count query into one

Tags: sql, group-by, count, left-join, inner-join

I have two very simple count queries that I would like to join into one.

To clarify the situation I will add the tables I got:

Book

| isbn | author |
| --- | --- |
| 1111 | GB |
| 2222 | DC |
| 3333 | RL |

Author

| code | Name |
| --- | --- |
| GB | George B. |
| KL | Kyle L. |
| DC | Donald C. |
| RL | Roland L. |

Coauthor

| name | isbn |
| --- | --- |
| KL | 1111 |
| GB | 2222 |
| GB | 3333 |

And the queries I made:
Query 1:

```
SELECT a.name, count(*) 
FROM coauthor c INNER JOIN author a ON c.name = a.code
GROUP BY a.name
```

Gives:

| name | Count(*) |
| --- | --- |
| KL | 1 |
| GB | 2 |

Query 2:

```
SELECT a.name, count(*) 
FROM author a INNER JOIN book b ON a.code = b.author
GROUP BY a.name
```

Gives:

| name | count(*) |
| --- | --- |
| GB | 1 |
| DC | 1 |
| RL | 1 |

And so I would like to get:

| name | count(*) |
| --- | --- |
| George B. | 3 |
| Donald C. | 1 |
| Roland L. | 1 |
| Kyle L. | 1 |

I have been searching the web, but I guess I don't know where to start.

Comment: Your queries doesn't match the columns of your tables. Please correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join `Author` to `Book` and `Coauthor` with `LEFT` joins and aggregate:

```
SELECT a.code, a.name, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT b.isbn) + COUNT(DISTINCT c.isbn) count
FROM Author a
LEFT JOIN Book b ON b.author = a.code
LEFT JOIN Coauthor c ON c.name = a.code
GROUP BY a.code, a.name;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0308b8722c44da8f37360edf40588abf).

Answer (score 0):

Union coauthor and book, then join those unique results to Author

```
SELECT q.code as Name
-- , a.name as Author
, COUNT(*) as Total
FROM
(
    SELECT name AS code, isbn
    FROM coauthor
    UNION
    SELECT author, isbn
    FROM book
) q
JOIN author a
  ON q.code = a.code
GROUP BY q.code, a.name
ORDER BY q.code
```

Note that normal `UNION` will filter the duplicate rows out.
While a `UNION ALL` keeps duplicate rows.